Get encrypted data from postgreSQL in Power BI
I was wondering how to connect to a PostgreSQL DB which is encrypted (AES-128-CBC), at data-level for several columns that contains sensitive data. It is running on a distant server. The version is 15.1 Alpine, the method crypt.c (pgcrypto).
I am trying to connect to that database from Power BI via a SQL query
I didn't find any information on the web regarding this type of encryption. Is it possible? How to do it?
In regards to the decryption key, is there a way to safekeep it inside the power BI ?

We don't understand where is the problem. The connection? The decryption?

I can't get to the data. I need to use a decryption in my query SQL with the key token, but I don't know the syntax or the SQL function associated

Start debugging this way:

Create a test PostgreSQL database on a different server and try to connect to that through Power BI. Use the default Power BI connector for PostreSQL. Is this working?
Now try to connect again to that test PostgreSQL database but this time through the SQL query. Is it working?
Now encrypt the test database with AES-128-CBC. Try to connect first with the official Power BI connector for PostgreSQL and then through the SQL query. Is it working with both?

This is how I would debug the whole thing
